# Born rule as the sudden approximation applied twice?

Tags: measurement

### Background

I haven't seen this done before as tempting as it seems and was wondering if there was some way to disprove the below? In short **can one think of the measurement as the [sudden approximation](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/timedependent.pdf) (Eq $84$ onwards or see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem#Diabatic_passage)) applied twice**? I use the notation:

$$ P(| A \rangle \to | B \rangle ) = \text{Probability of State $|A \rangle $ going to State $|B \rangle$}$$

And also:

$$ P(| A \rangle \to \sum | B \rangle ) = \text{Sum  of probabilities of State A going to one of the eigenstates of the observable of state $|B \rangle$}$$

### Proof

I define the measurement as a short lived interaction $H_{int}$ produced due to the measurement device.

Let the system I am interested in have the Hamiltonian $H$ obeying:

$$ H | E_n \rangle = E_n |E_n \rangle$$

The Hamiltonian of the short lived system (during the measurement) be $H'= H + H_{int}$ obeying:

$$ H' |E'_n \rangle = E'_n |E'_n \rangle $$

Thus we have the following sequence of Hamiltonians:

$$ H \to H' \to H $$

Let the initial state be $| \psi \rangle $ then after $H \to H'$ to find it in say state $| E' \rangle$ the probability is given by the sudden approximation.

$$ P(|\psi \rangle \to | E_n' \rangle ) = |\langle E_n' | \psi \rangle|^2  $$

Now, again let us assume the final state is $| \psi' \rangle$ after $H' \to H$. Then the probability of us arriving in that state is:

$$ P(|E_n' \rangle \to |\psi') =  |\langle E_n' | \psi '\rangle|^2$$

Hence, the probability of going from $|\psi \rangle \to |E'_n \rangle \to |\psi' \rangle  $ is:

$$P(|\psi \rangle \to |E'_n \rangle \to |\psi' \rangle) =|\langle E_n' | \psi \rangle|^2 |\langle E_n' | \psi '\rangle|^2 $$

Let's say I repeat the experiment many times and go through all $E_n'$ and somehow know the outcome $|\psi' \rangle$ but not the intermediate $E'_n$. Then:

$$ P(|\psi \rangle \to \sum |E'_n \rangle \to |\psi' \rangle) = \sum_{n} | \langle \psi' |E'_n \rangle \langle E'_n | \psi \rangle|^2 $$

Using triangle inequality and $\sum_n |E'_n \rangle \langle E'_n | = \hat 1 $:

$$ P(|\psi \rangle \to \sum | E'_n \rangle \to |\psi' \rangle) = |\langle \psi | \psi' \rangle |^2 + c(\psi \to \psi') \geq | \sum_n \langle \psi | E'_n  \rangle \langle E'_n | \psi ' \rangle |^2  $$

where $c$ is a constant:

$$ c(\psi  \to \psi') = \sum_{i \neq j} \langle \psi  | E_i \rangle \langle E_j | \psi ' \rangle \langle E_j | \psi \rangle \langle  \psi ' | E_i \rangle  $$

Now let's say we do the experiment many times and include all possible final outcomes of $| \psi ' \rangle $. Then what happens to $c$?

$$ \sum_{\psi'} c(\psi  \to \psi') =  \sum_{i \neq j} \sum_{\psi'} \langle \psi  | E_i \rangle \langle E_j | \psi ' \rangle \langle E_j | \psi \rangle \langle  \psi ' | E_i \rangle $$

But since $\sum_{'} |\psi' \rangle \langle \psi' | = \hat 1$:

$$ \sum_{\psi'} c(\psi  \to \psi') =  \sum_{i \neq j} \langle \psi  | E_i \rangle  \langle E_j | \psi \rangle \delta_{ij} = 0$$

Hence,

$$ P(|\psi \rangle \to \sum | E'_n \rangle \to \sum |\psi' \rangle) = | \langle \psi | \psi' \rangle |^2 $$

### Edit

After going through the derivation of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem#Diabatic_passage). It seems indeed the Born Rule itself is used to derive the didactic/sudden approximation. Precisely when the wikipedia page where it defines the parameter $\zeta$:

To determine the validity of the adiabatic approximation for a given process, one can calculate the probability of finding the system in a state other than that in which it started.

$$ \zeta = \underbrace{\langle 0 | U^\dagger (t_1 ,t_0) U (t_1 ,t_0) | 0\rangle}_{1} - \underbrace{\langle 0 | U^\dagger (t_1, t_0) | 0 \rangle  \langle 0 | U (t_1, t_0) | 0 \rangle}_{\text{Probability of finding state in $|0 \rangle$ after time evolution $t_1-t_0$}}   $$

Unless, there is some other way to get this result. In light of this I would like to ask if **this is a valid way to model the measurement** (as a consequence of double sudden approximations).

Comment: is this to be understood as trying to derive the Born rule from some other principle? If so, it looks like you are assuming it during the calculation, e.g. when you write the probability of transitions as $|\langle E_n'|\psi'\rangle|^2$

Comment: and how is that probability derived in the context of the sudden approximation?...

Comment: The sudden approximation says you should just ignore the intermediate Hamiltonian and pretend the whole evolution follows the normal Hamiltonian. How does double-ignoring the intermediate Hamiltonian change anything? Also, where are you getting the idea that there are probabilistic transitions implied by the sudden approximation; the whole thing should still be unitary?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous I don't understand why that brings in probabilities. The reference you linked describes nothing like that.

Comment: @glS You were right but I think the question is still valid.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean exactly with "model the measurement as a consequence of double sudden approximations". The "sudden approximation" is jus a way to approximate the dynamics in a specific regime. It doesn't say anything about measurements. The "sudden approx" only says that if H is changed fast enough, the state doesn't have the time to react and can be treated as unchanged in the process. Even the formula you were using doesn't really come from the "sudden approx", but rather is what Born says you would observe measuring immediately after the change of the Hamiltonian

Comment: @glS I think what I'm alluding to is that if the measurement postulate can be replaced by the sudden approximation?

Comment: Here what I mean by the sudden approximation is the probability of finding the wavefunction in state A after quickly perturbing the Hamiltonian is in the inner product modulus square of A and the original wacefunction.

Comment: but that's not what the sudden approximation says. The "sudden approximation" simply means to approximate the state as unchanged after the change in the Hamiltonian. It doesn't say anything about measurement probabilities.

Comment: @glS I agree with you. However, I am under the impression there a group of perhaps sloppy physicists who do not teach it like that for example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356858/transition-probability-sudden-approximation-if-the-perturbation-is-large

Comment: it doesn't seem like they are in that link. The given probabilities are just the result of the standard rules to obtain measurement probabilities from the state. Where are they saying that the square moduli do not come from Born's rule?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122672/discussion-between-more-anonymous-and-gls).